# Gradle script, how to execute a task (file copy) right after compilation and deploy

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

The following is my backend build.gradle for an android app.
After build and deploy, I would like to copy a few hibernate files to folders under build/exploded-app/. Instead of running gradlew cpyHibernate from terminal, how can I execute the cpyHibernate task from the script right after the deploy?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.18'
}
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.18'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.18'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.18'
    compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.1.5'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'hibernate:hibernate:3.1rc2'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.37'
}

appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
endpoints {
    getClientLibsOnBuild = true
    getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
    }
}

task cpyHibernate(type: Copy) {
    from 'src/main/java/hibernate.cfg.xml'
    into 'build/exploded-app/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/myapplication/backend/hbm/'
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can make some task finalizing another, in that case this task will run only if another one was called, right after it. You can read about it in the official [user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#N10F3E). This could be done as:

```
task cpyHibernate(type: Copy) {
    doFirst {
        //check anothe task status and skip this one if it didn't actually work
        if (!tasks.getByName("deploy").getState().didWork) {
            throw new StopExecutionException();
        }
    }
    from 'src/main/java/hibernate.cfg.xml'
    into 'build/exploded-app/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/myapplication/backend/hbm/'
}

deploy.finalizedBy cpyHibernate
```

You just have to know the deploy task name. In the example above, a supposed, that it's name is `deploy`. Note, your `cpyHibernate` is modified, to check, whether `deploy` task actally did some work and is not up-to-date. If you don't need it, just remove the `doFirst` section from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `build` and `deploy` tasks as dependencies for `cpyHibernate` task.

After declaring task:

```
cpyHibernate { ... }    
cpyHibernate.dependsOn build, deploy
```

Or in one place:

```
task cpyHibernate(type: Copy, dependsOn: [build, deploy]) {
    from 'src/main/java/hibernate.cfg.xml'
    into 'build/exploded-app/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/myapplication/backend/hbm/'
}
```